# MongoDB query executiontime takes long time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created one query for calculating average

```
db.voltage.aggregate([
    {
$match: {
    $and: [ 
            {EventTS: {$gte: ISODate("2016-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000")}},
            {EventTS: {$lte: ISODate("2016-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000")}}
        ]
    }
},
    {$project: {
        date: {
          $dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$EventTS"}},
          KeyValues:1
    }},

    {$unwind: '$KeyValues'},
    {$project: {
       date: 1,
       RVoltage: '$KeyValues.RVoltage',
       YVoltage: '$KeyValues.YVoltage',
       BVoltage: '$KeyValues.BVoltage'
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$date',
        ravg: {$avg: '$RVoltage'},
        yavg: {$avg: '$YVoltage'},
        bavg: {$avg: '$BVoltage'}
    }},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
])
```

My collection contains

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9407ffbe031fa2049e3"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-07-01T04:30:00.000+0530"), 
    "KeyValues" : [
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 222.52
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9407ffbe031fa2049e4"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-07-01T05:30:00.000+0530"), 
    "PanelID" : "A01699", 
    "KeyValues" : [
        {
            "RVoltage" : 233.28
        },  
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 233.37
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9407ffbe031fa2049e8"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-07-01T05:30:00.000+0530"), 
    "PanelID" : "A00795", 
    "KeyValues" : [
        {
            "RVoltage" : 238.72
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 237.08
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 235.2
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 238.14
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9407ffbe031fa2049ec"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-07-01T05:30:00.000+0530"), 
    "PanelID" : "A00540", 
    "KeyValues" : [
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 249.01
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 246.49
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 246.78
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 247.47
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9407ffbe031fa2049ed"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-07-01T05:30:00.000+0530"), 
    "PanelID" : "A00946", 
    "KeyValues" : [
        {
            "RVoltage" : 248.67
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 249.91
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 248.82
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 247.01
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9407ffbe031fa2049ee"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-07-01T05:30:00.000+0530"), 
    "PanelID" : "A01132", 
    "KeyValues" : [
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 230.79
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9407ffbe031fa2049f0"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-07-01T05:30:00.000+0530"), 
    "PanelID" : "A01006", 
    "KeyValues" : [
        {
            "RVoltage" : 262.01
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 261.21
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 261.18
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : 261.61
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9407ffbe031fa2049f4"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-07-01T05:30:00.000+0530"), 
    "PanelID" : "A01682", 
    "KeyValues" : [
        {
            "RVoltage" : 232.93
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
            "RVoltage" : null
        }, 
        {
```

When i execute this query, it takes more than 30 seconds for more than 500k records. What is wrong in my query and why it is taking time to execute?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, are you having the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692618/how-to-calculate-average-per-day-field-using-mongodb considering you have identical schemas ?

Comment: yes we are working on same project and we are facing same problem and we have to resolve this issue as early as possible. Hence we both put same issue to get answer from any of question as  soon as possible

Comment: I think you should read about the [indexes in Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) before asking about the performance of queries. When we are speaking about performance, indexes are main thing we should know to understand what is going on.

Comment: @RomanR. we have already applied indexing on that field but then too it takes time

Comment: @Amit can you execute this query on your database and post the  result here https://gist.github.com/bearburger/ddb5bff5211d30ccfb244860ad9234d3 EventTS parameters should be like the same on your main query where you are starting to face performance issues.